# Order of execution unexpectedly affecting the outcome

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I am running this code on Python3 shell.

```
numberList = [1, 2, 3]
strList = ['one', 'two', 'three']

result=zip(numberList, strList)

resultSet=set(result)   #1
resultList=list(result)  #2

print(resultSet)
print(resultList)
```

and I am very surprised with the outcome :

```
{(1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')}
[]            <<< Why?
```

Further, when I **swap** `line#1` with `line#2`, the outcome is similar to the earlier one:

```
set()         <<< Why? 
[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]
```

What could be the reason behind later one being empty? 
Am I missing any concept here? FYI, I am relatively new to Python.

Comment: `zip` gives you an iterable... `list` and `set` will consume that iterable making it effectively "empty"... following attempts to consume it will have nothing to consume. Think I've seen Q/As with various examples and how you to need to do it... I'll have a look...

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest doing `resultList=list(result); resultSet = set(resultList)`

Comment: @JonClements ok, that makes sense now. Didn't know how to google it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `result=zip(numberList, strList)` returns an **iterator**. It is similar to what `itertools.izip` did in python 2.x
Previously in python 2 `zip` used to return tuple.

From python 3 `zip` returns an iterator. An iterator returns value only once. When second time one tries to iterate over it then gives no output.

If you need to use the it again you should consider using it as

```
numberList = [1, 2, 3]
strList = ['one', 'two', 'three']

result=list(zip(numberList, strList)) # check the "list" keyword added 


resultList=list(result)  #2
resultSet=set(result)   #1

print(resultSet)
print(resultList)
```

Comment: Your "answer" isn't nearly half as descriptive as the comments, would you consider putting some effort into the answer please?

Comment: Edited the answer. I realised after posting that its only giving you a hint than an answer why it is behaving such a way